# Browser says two dimensional object is undefined

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, browser

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const keypad = document.querySelector("#keypad");

  const widthN = 4;
  const heightN = 5;
  const keysN = [];

  const widthA = 7;
  const heightA = 5;
  const keysA = [];

  let button_dataN = [
    [ "C",  "()", "%", "/" ],
    [ "7",  "8",  "9", "*" ],
    [ "4",  "5",  "6", "-" ],
    [ "1",  "2",  "3", "+" ],
    ["+/-", "0",  ".", "=" ]
  ];

  createKeypadN()

  function createKeypadN() {
    keyPadBody = document.createElement("div");
    keyPadBody.setAttribute("id", "keyPadBody")
    keypad.appendChild(keyPadBody);

    for (let i = 0; i < widthN * heightN; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < widthN; j++) {
        const key = document.createElement("button");
        key.innerHTML = button_dataN[i][j];
        key.setAttribute("id", button_dataN[i][j]);

        keyPadBody.appendChild(key);
        keyPadBody.style.height = "250px";
        keyPadBody.style.width = "200px";

        key.style.height = "50px";
        key.style.width = "50px";
        keysN.push(key);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="keypad"></div>
```

The whole code works fine but the browser throws this:

*

> Uncaught TypeError: button_dataN[i] is undefined
> createKeypadN *file:///home/path/to/calculator/main.js:38*
>  *file:///home/path/to/calculator/main.js:95*
> EventListener.handleEvent* *file:///home/path/to/calculator/main.js:1*

- 

Comment: `widthN * heightN` is probably bigger than `button_dataN.length`.

Comment: How is defined `widthN` and `heightN`? -- Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Comment: Sorry I thought I added the widthN and heightN, it has been edited

Comment: You've got i ranging from 0 to height * width...which is not how many items you have in that dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
for (let i = 0; i < widthN * heightN; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < widthN; j++) {
```

with

```
for (let i = 0; i < heightN; i++) {  // Each "rows"
  for (let j = 0; j < widthN; j++) {  // Each "columns"
```

Those `i` and `j` variable are loop indexes... There is one loop to go through the *"rows"* and one to go throught the *"columns"* of what you seem to interpret like a speadsheet.

With your code, you were looping rows from 0 to 19 intead of 0 to 4.

So the error occured when the script tried `button_dataN[5][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this code

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>
  {
  const 
    keypad = document.querySelector('#keypad')
  , keysN  = []
  , button_dataN =
      [ [  'C', '()', '%', '/' ] 
      , [  '7',  '8', '9', '*' ] 
      , [  '4',  '5', '6', '-' ] 
      , [  '1',  '2', '3', '+' ] 
      , [ '+/-', '0', '.', '=' ] 
      ];
  keyPadBody    = keypad.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
  keyPadBody.id = 'keyPadBody';

  for (let keyVal of  button_dataN.flat())
    {
    let key = keyPadBody.appendChild( document.createElement('button'))
    key.textContent = key.id  = keyVal;
    keysN.push(key);
    }
  })
```

```css
#keyPadBody {
  height: 250px;
  width : 200px;
  }
#keyPadBody button {
  height: 50px;
  width : 50px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="keypad"></div>
```